# SSIS C# scripting to return values to a SQL task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, bids

I am attempting to take information or values from an excel 97 format sheet and convert it to a specific string. I need to then transport this string to a SQL task to be stored in the database.

1. Is it possible to do this?
2. If so, how would this be done?

Comment: I have C# code to manipulate the data in the excel sheet, but I have never tried c# scripting inside an SSIS package. I dont even know where to begin.

Comment: Does it need to be SSIS? I have a solution in a different ETL program.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Data flow task with Excel as source connection and oledb as destination with derived column as transformation to convert string

Comment: How would you handle the sheets in said workbook? a foreach loop?

Comment: Add Execute sql task using ado.net connection manager to read all Excel sheets and then for each to read from that object and then.load in table